# Merging images result in duplicate first and last merged images

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, pdf-conversion

I wrote a photobook converter in Python. It works but when the results are output to a PDF, the last pair of images are duplicated in the front although I've double-checked the pairs.

```
from PIL import Image

imagelist = ['backlit-bonding-casual.jpg', 'business-meeting.jpg', 'city-community-crossing.jpg', 'sunglass_face.jpg', 'multiple_faces.jpg', 'happy_face.jpg', 'vegas.jpg', 'busy-street-crowd-crowded.jpg', 'no_face.jpg', 'pittsburgh.jpg', 'seattle.jpg', 'victoria.jpg']

def openimage(list):
    # gotta get list first
    # then open image, resize image, save image
    # append to list
    global new_list
    new_list = []
    for i in list:
        image = Image.open(i)
        width, height = image.size
        # if image is portrait, rotate it:
        if height > width:
            image = image.rotate(90, expand=True)
        image.thumbnail((1754, 1240))
        image_filename = i.split(".")[0]
        image.save(image_filename + '.jpg', format='JPEG')
        new_list.append(image_filename + '.jpg')
    print("This is the new list:", new_list)

openimage(imagelist)

def split_list(modifiedlist):
    # zip one list into pairs to create pairs of images
    global pairedlist
    for x in modifiedlist:
        if len(modifiedlist) % 2 == 0:
            pairedlist = list(zip(modifiedlist[::2], modifiedlist[1::2]))
        else:
            # create pair list with None type (or whatever you want as placeholder)
            # imagelist.append(None)
            pairedlist = list(zip(modifiedlist[::2], modifiedlist[1::2]))
    print("This is the paired list:", pairedlist)

split_list(new_list)

def convert_to_PDF(list, pdfname):
    # convert pairs of jpg files into multiple PDF pages
    # append pages to each other to make 1 file, save all pages
    merged_imagelist = []
    for x, y in list:
        image1 = Image.open(x)
        image2 = Image.open(y)
        merged_image = Image.new('RGB', (image1.width, image1.height + image2.height))
        merged_image.paste(image1, (0,0))
        merged_image.paste(image2, (0, image1.height))
        merged_image = merged_image.convert('RGB')
        merged_imagelist.append(merged_image)
    merged_image.save(pdfname, save_all=True, append_images=merged_imagelist)

convert_to_PDF(pairedlist, 'testfilepath.pdf')
```

This is my output:

```
This is the new list: ['backlit-bonding-casual.jpg', 'business-meeting.jpg', 'city-community-crossing.jpg', 'sunglass_face.jpg', 'multiple_faces.jpg', 'happy_face.jpg', 'vegas.jpg', 'busy-street-crowd-crowded.jpg', 'no_face.jpg', 'pittsburgh.jpg', 'seattle.jpg', 'victoria.jpg']
This is the paired list: [('backlit-bonding-casual.jpg', 'business-meeting.jpg'), ('city-community-crossing.jpg', 'sunglass_face.jpg'), ('multiple_faces.jpg', 'happy_face.jpg'), ('vegas.jpg', 'busy-street-crowd-crowded.jpg'), ('no_face.jpg', 'pittsburgh.jpg'), ('seattle.jpg', 'victoria.jpg')]
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: `list` is a reserved keyword, I recommend you to replace it! with `my_list` for example.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up modifying my code. 

For the record, I also ended up figuring out what caused the duplicate entries:

It was 

`merged_image.save(pdfname, save_all=True, append_images=merged_imagelist)`

The way I saved my merged_image meant that I appended the rest of the list (including the pair already saved), resulting in a duplicate. I ended up splicing the last item so that it wouldn't result in a duplicate first and final pair:

`merged_image.save(pdfname, save_all=True, append_images=merged_imagelist[:-1])`